# Introducing a proper noun

Tags: adjectives, proper-nouns

I wrote:

> The dependents of a head node are enclosed with a *Children* node and the dependency relations are stored within the child nodes.

It is in fact:

> The dependents of a head node are enclosed with a node labeled with *Children* and the dependency relations are stored within the child nodes.

where the *Children* is a label. Can I directly introduce this proper name as an adjective like in the first sentence.

Comment: ... are enclosed **within** a container node labelled "Children". Once you have made that statement, you can refer to "the *Children* node"  if you place Children in italics for the sake of clarity, as you have done, to prevent confusion.  If the head node can contain only one *Children* node, I'd say **the** *Children* node, but if the head node can contain more than one *Children* node, then **a** *Children* node would be OK.

Comment: Thank you, in fact in the original XML the label is "children" in lower case, should I use it in italic and in lower case after introduced it?

Comment: That doesn’t make it an adjective. It’s still a noun.

Comment: Contained nodes are by convention referred to as "child nodes" of a "parent node", and so readers are going to already have in their heads the phrase  "a child node" and they are likely to stumble a little when they encounter "a children node".  They're going to expect the singular "child".  That's why you need to do something typographically special here with the label "Children".  I would retain upper case:  *Children* and "container node", not simply "node":  "the *Children* container-node."

Comment: @TRomano: Your comment should be an answer. I thought exactly the same thing, down to the "container node".

Comment: I didn't make it a full-fledged answer because it was based on my reading of books and articles on this subject, rather than on particular requirements of the English language. It's just good advice.  :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may refer to a labeled item using the label in quotation marks as an adjective. In this case:

> The dependents of a head node are enclosed in a "children" node and the dependency relations are stored within the child nodes.

Proper nouns are capitalized, so if you want to use it as a proper noun you should use Children. There are many ways of phrasing this that are grammatically correct. As the top comment says, you may say:

> ... enclosed within a container node labeled "Children" ...

One important thing to remember is the the capitalization should match exactly the *actual* label of the node, since the quotation marks imply that it is verbatim.

After introducing the label it would make sense to refer to "the Children node" (no quotation marks) or "the 'children' node" (with quotation marks).